# Pandas get column values based on duplicate rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a sample DF:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size = (6,2)),columns=["A","B"])
df["col"] = ["Apple","Apple","Mango","Apple","Mango","Apple"]
df
```

OP:

```
    A   B   col
0   3   9   Apple
1   8   8   Apple
2   7   9   Mango
3   2   4   Apple
4   4   5   Mango
5   1   6   Apple
```

I am trying to get the values of columns - `"A" and "B"` wherever there are duplicate values in column `col`. For example the column `col` has value `Apple` in index - `0,1,3,5` and I am trying to get the respective values in column - `A and B`, ie

```
 {"Apple":[[3,9],[8,8],[2,4],[1,6]], "Mango": [[7,9],[4,5]]}
```

I have a iterative approach which takes a long time on big Dfs.

Current Approach:

-> Find Unique values in column `col`

```
unique_values = list(df["col"].unique())
```

-> Iterate through this list and a inner loop through every row of the DF to  get the required OP:

```
op = {}
for i in range(len(unique_values)):
    for index, rows in df.iterrows():
        if rows ["col"] == unique_values[i]:
            inner_op = []
            inner_op.append(rows["A"]);inner_op.append(rows["B"])
            if rows["col"] in op:
                op[rows["col"]].append(inner_op)
            else:
                op[rows["col"]] = [inner_op]
```

final OP:

```
{'Apple': [[3, 9], [8, 8], [2, 4], [1, 6]], 'Mango': [[7, 9], [4, 5]]}
```

Is there any suggestions for a more pandas approach which could be more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create column filled by list `C` convert values to numpy array and to list and then aggregate `list` by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with [`Series.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
np.random.seed(2020)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size = (6,2)),columns=["A","B"])
df["col"] = ["Apple","Apple","Mango","Apple","Mango","Apple"]

df['C'] = df[['A','B']].to_numpy().tolist()
d = df.groupby('col')['C'].agg(list).to_dict()
print (d)
{'Apple': [[0, 8], [3, 6], [7, 8], [8, 9]], 'Mango': [[3, 3], [0, 0]]}
```